# Jackson - reject null values, but allow absent values

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am deserializing a JSON into a model with Jackson. Say I have the following model:

```
class Model {
    private String           fieldA;
    private Optional<String> fieldB;
}
```

Here, `fieldA` is non-nullable. In the JSON, it can either be absent or filled in:

```
{

}
```

or

```
{
    "fieldA": "value"
}
```

In Java, the not filled in-case results in a null value of the member `fieldA`.

My question: is there a way to reject a null value for `fieldA`? For the following input JSON, Jackson should throw an exception:

```
{
    "fieldA": null
}
```

Note that I only want that behaviour for `fieldA`, and not `fieldB`, since `fieldB` is nullable (and hence it is wrapped around an `Optional` in the model).

I could also wrap `fieldA` in an `Optional` and add some bean validation there, but I would rather not change the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Jackson does not provide validation API. You can just ignore null value by including `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` to the class or use [Bean Validation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) which will validate and throw errors if conditions are not satisfied.

**UPDATE:**

For your comment answer, if anyhow you just wanted to skip fieldA value if it is null and let other allowed them than in setter method you could just manually check.

In your case:

```
public void setFieldA(String fieldA) {

    if (fieldA != null) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` is that when `fieldA` in the model is null, I have no way to find out if it is `null` because it was absent in input JSON (which is OK), or because it was given a null value in the input JSON (which is not OK).

Comment: This makes sense! I did not think about implementing the setter. Thanks, useful answer!